# How to measure IEnumerable<T> evaluation time?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a lazy linq query which discovers the number of elements in some xml in memory which contains a particular attribute. I want to assess the length of time it will take to enumerate that query for varying lengths of xml.

In order to do this I first considered using a call to .ToList() as I know that causes an enumeration of all Items. However I decided that this might not represent full evaluation time as there would be a memory operation to move all items from one structure to another and so switched to a call to .Count().

```
IEnumerable<XMLNode> nodes = "<Some Linq>"

var watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Restart();
var test = nodes.Count();
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Enumeration Time: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

First question would be is this the best way to calculate the time it takes to evaluate that Enumerable?

Second question would be which is more representative of the actual evaluation time Count() or ToList()?

Here are some results from the code, note that between iterations a new portion of xml is added, this means that the xml being searched grows by the same amount each time.

**Resuts (from .Count())**

```
Enumeration Time: 0 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 0 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 1 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 1 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 2 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 2 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 2 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 3 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 3 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 4 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 4 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 5 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 6 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 6 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 8 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 6 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 15 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 8 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 8 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 9 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 8 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 9 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 10 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 10 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 10 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 27 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 12 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 18 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 20 (ms)
```

**Resuts (from .ToList())**

```
Enumeration Time: 1 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 1 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 1 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 2 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 2 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 3 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 3 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 4 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 4 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 5 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 5 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 9 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 14 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 12 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 10 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 8 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 9 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 10 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 13 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 12 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 12 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 16 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 21 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 18 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 15 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 15 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 23 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 15 (ms)
Enumeration Time: 38 (ms)
```

Comment: You could enumerate the LINQ result with a foreach loop, that should have a minimal overhead i think (the overhead you always have).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using `var test = nodes.Count();` is that the underlying collection (if there is one) might be implementing `IList<T>` which has a `Count` property.

As an optimization that property could be called and you would get near constant time whatever size the collection.

Instead of `ToList()` *or* `Count()` consider actually iterating:

```
foreach(var item in nodes){}
```

Note that we are not doing anything with the `item` - this will just iterate with minimal overheads.

Comment: I have no idea what he did try to do there... can you please explain in short ? he wanted to measure the time that deferred execution is filling the ienumerable ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - He is using LINQ with XML files and is trying to measure how long iterating over collections of different sizes would take. He wants to minimize any other possible variables and is wondering how to achieve this (`ToList()` was rejected as it consumes memory to build the list and return it eagerly and he wanted to know if there is a better way than calling `Count()` on the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really make a useful performance test like that for reading from a file.

The performance will vary greatly depending on whether the file is in the disk cache or not. In your test the file will always be cached as you accessed it milliseconds ago, but in a live situation it would rarely be, which would give a completely different result.

You could test only the part of parsing the file data, by reading it from a `MemoryStream` instead of a real file. However, reading the actual file will normally take a lot longer than parsing it, so the performance of the parsing is generally not critical at all.

Comment: Sorry I probably should have worded that differently, the XML is in Memory at the time of this test. Will edit the question.